# TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNCCameraRoll' could not be found [React Native Expo]

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera, camera-roll

I'm trying to use camera roll in a react native project, so far tried libraries "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll" and "expo-image-picker".

However, on both iPhone and Android, I get an error "TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNCCameraRoll' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary."

I tried to manually link with "npx react native link @react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll" but it looks like manual linking is disabled now. I've also tried "npx react-native-asset" but still getting the same error.

Expo 6.3.1; iphone 13; Android 9

- tried libraries "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll" and "expo-image-picker", on both ios and Android
- tried to manually link with "npx react native link @react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll"
- tried "npx react-native-asset"

Answer (score 1):

Update: I cleared cache according to https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/clear-cache-windows/ , and after that expo-image-picker worked. Still not able to make @react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll work but I'll just use expo-image-picker instead.